# Can I copy from VHD to physical disk to replace my host OS?

Tags: vhd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying a VHD to a physical disk](https://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk)

I am planning to upgrade from a 32 bit os (Vista) to 64 bit (7). As there is no straight upgrade path, and I do not want to spend an entire weekend setting everything up with no immediate rollback (apart from an image), is there a way I can make a virtual disk with Windows 7 and then copy this to the physical hard drive and override my host OS (Vista)?

So in short I have Vista as my host OS, I setup 7 on a VHD, but in the end 7 becomes my host OS just like Vista is now.

Comment: See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the similar question I posted, if you don't have a second disk you can boot from, you can use a Linux LiveCD such as [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) and use `dd` from there.

You can also image the virtual environment with [Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost) or [Clonezilla (free)](http://clonezilla.org/) and then restore that image to your host.

Comment: Thanks for that. BTW I mean replacing the current host OS (just to be clear) :)

Comment: In serverfault there is a similar question and the suggestion is again to use dd (http://serverfault.com/questions/296697/how-can-i-copy-a-vhd-image-back-to-a-physical-disc). Has anyone actually tried this or the suggestion is only by intuition? I'd hate to wait for several hours dd to complete only to find out that the disk won't boot.

Could someone confirm and post a snippet? I'd guess it would be something like:

dd if=/path/to/your.vhd of=/dev/sdX bs=4096