# How to Copy .VHD File to Physical Hard Disk Using DD Command

Tags: backup, restore, vhd, dd, disk-image

I have read other question/answers on this site that say this is possible, but I'm wondering how it is done. I have tried the following command, which completes successfully, but the NTFS isn't valid on the drive afterwards.

```
$ dd if=\backup\image.vhd of=\dev\sda
```

Does the `.vhd` file have to be mounted somehow first? Will this restore the `MBR`?

Thank you.

[Reference Question](https://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk)

Answer (score 7):

The VHD file isn't a raw image format (like DD uses), so you will have to use something to convert it to a raw format.

Looking at the VBoxManage webpage the following command *should* work, but I haven't tried it:

```
$ VBoxManage clonehd /backup/image.vhd - --format RAW | dd of=/dev/sda
```

As I say I haven't tried it, but you could read up on VBoxManage at the VirtualBox website:

- http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Comment: I get `error: unknown option: -` using version 7.0.12. I looks like clonehd is now an alias of clonemedium

Answer (score 1):

For later reference, I had the following issue:

- DELL Precision 390 with Linux/Debian wheezy installed (X86_64)
- A VHDX backup of the pre-installed Windows XP 64bits (see [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx))
- A BKF backup of all the files using the default [NTBackup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTBackup) program
- No Windows XP 64bits rescue disk

My issue was to reset the system back to Windows XP 64bits.

Attempts:

- I did not understand a word of the solution described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/791855/how-to-complete-restore-using-just-a-vhdx-file), but I am mostly a UNIX guy. The following [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320820) did not make much sense either.
- There were a couple of solutions described from a Windows 8 installation, but I had no Windows 8 disk for testing.
- I re-installed Windows XP 32bits (I had a spare disk), but I was not sure if I could use the BKF file to overwrite an existing Windows XP 32bits with the files contained in the BKF file.
- After reading information from this [link](http://www.storagecraft.com/support/book/export/html/12647):

> Note: Use the Recovery Environment for Windows to restore from a
>   VHD/VHDX formatted image file. The Recorvery Environment CrossPlatform
>   only supports restores from .SPF and .SPI image files, not from VHD or
>   VHDX format files.

- I used a Windows 7 32bits Windows Recovery Environment disk, click on "Windows Complete PC Restore". After an insane amount of trials I could never get this tool to see neither the BKF, the VHDX nor the VHD ([converted using VBoxManage](https://superuser.com/a/796838)). I tried using a shared network drive, I could hear the disk spinning but the drive would file would never show up on the interface, I even tried from a USB key, but again the tool would not let me pick the USB key option (I do not want to use the DVD drive option since I had no RW+ DVD around). VBoxManage really does support VHDX file, even if this is not mentioned in the documentation, as per [link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=772844).

I was about to give up until, I found this post, and I can happily report that this is working nicely for me.

Steps were as easy as:

- Open the DELL Precision 390 case, remove the hard drive
- Plug it into a Debian Jessie (x86_64) system
- Use `gnome-disks` to clear up the disk partitions, just click the "-" (minus) sign, write down the /dev/sd[Letter] somewhere (sdf in my case), double check that the disk is not mounted,
- Run the following command `VBoxManage clonehd windows_xp64.VHDX --format RAW windows_xp64.RAW`
- Run `sudo dd if=windows_xp64.RAW of=/dev/sdf`

`dd` eventually displays:

```
dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdf’: No space left on device
488281251+0 records in
488281250+0 records out
250000000000 bytes (250 GB) copied, 32825.4 s, 7.6 MB/s
```

Indeed looking at the file:

```
$ ls -al windows_xp64.RAW
-rw------- 1 mathieu mathieu 250000048128 Dec 11 20:02 windows_xp64.RAW
```

I figured this could be discarded since the last 48128 bytes were all zeroes, I am not sure where those extra bytes came from (disk2vhd or VBoxManage...).

I had to use a two (very slow) steps approach, because VBoxManage does not pipe to stdout, at least from my debian jessie installation,

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 4.3.18-dfsg-1
  Candidate: 4.3.18-dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.18-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

It seems to still be an issue upstream, as per [Enable writing to STDOUT with VBoxManage clonehd in raw format](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6650).

There might have been an easier solution using the BKF file but I never found out one for sure.