# How to convert a VHDX file to VHD?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vhd

I made an image with disk2vhd and unfortunately I chose VHDX instead of VHD. I didn't see any information about what to choose.

Anyway, now that file is all I have, the original PC is trashed. So I need to know how to run it as a Virtual Machine in Windows 7.

VirtualBox doesn't have an option to open VHDX and WM Converter doesn't have an option to open VHDX (or to convert to VHD).

Answer (score 53):

You can do that conversion with VirtualBox :

```
VBoxManage.exe clonemedium "input_file.vhdx" "output_file.vhd" --format VHD
```

Default Path to `VBoxManage.exe`

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
```

Comment: It looks like this is [broken in VirtualBox 5.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14288). The report is labeled as "critical", but hasn't been modified in 7 months, so not very optimistic.

Comment: @WasabiFan - it works again in 5.1.4 (I just used it).

Comment: Also, one can encounter the `VHDX: Image has a non empty log which is not supported (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)` error message.

Comment: Works in VirtualBox 7.0.

Answer (score 12):

**Before anything, make a backup of the original .VHDX, just in case.**

You said you have Windows 7. In that case, you can easily convert VHDX to VHD with PowerShell.

Go to "Run..." (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `Powershell`.

Then, in the PowerShell command line, type the command `PS C:\> Convert-VHD –Path YOUR VHDX PATH –DestinationPath YOUR DESTINATION PATH`

It should be converted then.

You can find additional information about the `Convert-VHD` command [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848454.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I give it a try.

But it says >> Applies To: Windows 8.1, Windows PowerShell 4.0, Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: @Bjorn - Powershell 4 will work on Windows 7.

Comment: this is a cmdlet which only works in Win8/Server 2012 when Hyper-V is activated.

Comment: Hyper-V is not available in Home editions.

Comment: Even after upgrading to PowerShell 4.0 I just get `The term 'Convert-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` on Windows 7

Comment: Go to Turn Windows Features on and off > Hyper-V > Hyper-V Management Tools > Hyper-V module for Windows PowerShell and enable it.

Answer (score 6):

To convert vhdx to vhd use the free [StarWind V2V Image Converter](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter)

Comment: Just tried it, only works on Win8 or above.

Comment: It worked for me on W10. You can download it here: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/tmplink/starwindconverter.exe

Answer (score 5):

I made the same mistake, when creating the Virtual disk from the physical with Disk2VHD, there is a check box at the top right (second down) that is ticked by default to create a vhdx,  Remove this check and it will create a vhd instead.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to extract files from a Windows 10 VMDH "Windows Image Backup" and to write them to a Windows 7 machine: I installed Windows Server 2012 (free 180 days evaluation) in a virtual machine and connected it to my local hard disk via a network share. This way I could "mount" the VMDH backup and write the important files back to my local drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open CMD as Admin, and type the following command to switch to VirtualBox folder:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
```

2. Then type this command to convert from VHDX to VHD:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw "C:\Full-Path-To\image.VHDX" "C:\Full-Path-To\new-image.VHD" --format VHD
```

After that, I would prefer giving the result VHD image a new UUID by using this command:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid "C:\Full-Path-To\new-image.VHD"
```

Extra step I usually do when converting/cloning images in VirtualBox as it tends to show many errors when it finds 2 images with the same UUID. Unlike Hyper-V doesn't care for that.

**Note:**
These commands mentioned above are case sensitive! (convertfromraw - internalcommands - sethduuid)