# How to attach VHDX file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, restore, vhdx

I made a Windows 10 backup, and now I have 2 VHDX files. If I attack that on Windows 10 in disk manager, no problem, but I must attach on Windows 7, and unforunatelly that doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error you get.

Comment: Haven't you tried to convert the vhdx to vhd on a Windows 10 PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 doesn't support VHDX file format. This is only supported in Windows 8(.1) and Windows 10. For [Windows 7, you need to convert the VHDX to VHD](https://superuser.com/q/751954/174557).

Comment: Thank you! I will try It! 

I found an other solution: open VHDX with isobuster program.