# How to complete restore using just a VHDX file?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-8.1, vhd

Let me please explain the scenario what I went through.

I have a Transcend SSD which I use to boot my PC which I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1.

I have two other hard disk drives (one tera byte and other is 320 GB). Yesterday I received a notification from the SSD utility that there is a firmware update available. I read the instructions which came along it which stated that the drive will be completely erased if I update it. Naturally I had to backup the entire drive. I used the command :

```
wbAdmin start backup -backupTarget:F: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

The F drive was my other hard drive of 320 GB (Single partition).

It took a while and came the message that the backup has been done successfully.

I made a system restore disk using the utility from the control panel.

I then made the firmware update usb drive by the utility provided and then booted from the USB and successfully updated the firmware.

Then I booted from the system restore disk I created earlier to restore my old image. However when I tried to restore it, it tried to restore it on my other hard drive instead. I then went to command prompt, used the `diskpart` command and accidentally selected the wrong drive (the one which contained my backup) and used the `clean` command.

And there my whole backup was gone!

I then installed a fresh OS using my original DVD (of Windows 8) on the SSD. I tried the recovery tools and all I was able to recover is my VHDX file (which is usually inside the folders created by the `wbAdmin` command). I tried mounting the image and thankfully it is safe and I can mount it.

Now the thing is that I want to write the complete VHDX file to my SSD so that I can get back my old and working OS.

Can anyone please help me with the things I have? I just have my VHDX file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I realize this is two years too late but having just gone through a similar experience with Windows 10, I finally came across this [post](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/32012-how-install-vhdx-image-onto-win-10-new-computer-post492152.html#post492152) which helped me resolve my problem. I needed to convert the VHD/VHDX from my Windows Backup to a Windows Imaging Format (WIM) disk file and restore that to my C: drive.

Before starting, you'll need the exact path to the VHDX for the Mount command.

Assuming the system image backup or other VHDX resides on an external drive D: (change the D: drive letter to match the location of your backup VHD/VHDX):

1. Connect the backup drive containing the backup to another Windows PC.
2. Open a PowerShell command window as Administrator.
3. Create a "Mount" and "Capture" folder on D:.

> md D:\Mount, D:\Capture

4. Mount the VHDX at D:\Mount.

> Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath "D:\*full_path_to*.vhdx" -Path D:\Mount -Index 1

5. Write the "Mount" folder to a new WIM file.

> New-WindowsImage -CapturePath D:\Mount -Name Win10Backup -ImagePath D:\Capture\Backup.wim -Description "Windows 10 Backup" -Verify

6. Once completed, unmount the VHDX and safely disconnect the backup drive.

> Dismount-WindowsImage -Path D:\Mount -Discard

On the computer to restore, connect the drive containing the WIM file, boot up the Windows 10 setup media and from the install screen select "Repair Computer" > "Troubleshoot" > "Advanced Options" > "Command Prompt".

(You may need to use DiskPart from the command line to make sure C: refers to your desired C: partition.)

From the command line, format and then restore the C: drive from the WIM:

> format c: /q
>
> Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:D:\Capture\Backup.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\

Once completed, cross your fingers and reboot.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I have a "Windows image backup" (VHDX file) but the regular Windows restore utility refused to restore it, saying (something like) there was not a suitable place to restore it to. I found at least three different explanations of why this could happen and tried their workarounds - nothing. This technique worked. Really makes me wonder why Microsoft doesn't provide an override on whatever checks it's making; as this backup is obviously perfectly good!

Comment: Windows build-in restore only returned errors: 0x800703ed (the volume doesn't contain a recognizable file system) and 0x80070057 (the parameter is incorrect). Whatever workaround was tried, ejecting disks, etcetera. This method took al long time to convert at USB2 speed, but worked!

Comment: Will this work if instead of mounting the vhdx you are native booted from the vhdx?

Comment: Should command 5 show progress or just sit at the command prompt for like hours?

Comment: Yes, the "New-WindowsImage" command takes a long, long time before it starts to show any progress. Converting a 500GB image on an i7, it took a couple of hours before the command show the progress bar. :(

Comment: Omg can not tell you how much you saved me thank you

Comment: Do you think it might work for a Hyper-V VHDX file? I want to restore my hyper-v disk into the host of another of pc of mine.

Comment: It may be possible but I’ve never tried it myself. The difference of course is drivers. A machine created through Hyper-V is very generic. If it does copy over and run, you’ll need to download the appropriate hardware drivers to get the physical installation optimized. At that point, you have to ask yourself if it’s worth the time and effort vs. building from scratch and copying over data.

Comment: Great post. It worked perfectly with one error `Operating system not found`. Then this article helped me to mark the volume containing windows as active. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-an-operating-system-wasn-t-found-error-when-booting-windows-2c149e3a-dc37-0322-4d79-336f3888906b

Answer (score 3):

After finding this question I want to add how I did a restore. I maintain a friend's computer who lives down the street. When machines are new I always clone the system drive to a second OS on the same hard disk, and when issues occur I boot to the second OS. This only requires a small amount of space. Over a year ago I made VHDX images of both drives, the main and second OS, which is my normal backup procedure. She had not been using the laptop much, so not much was changed, but her grandson was there playing with it. Both operating systems became unusable due to partial windows updates.

To resolve this I performed the following steps:
- removed the hard disk and plugged into a dock on another machine
- created a VHDX file for the main partition
- with EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition I wrote down the partition sizes
- with EaseUS I deleted both partitions
- with Disk Management I mounted the VHDX backup file of the main partition
- with EaseUs I cloned the mounted drive to unallocated space
- I reinstalled the hard disk in the laptop
- I booted to a windows DVD and repaired the boot up
- I removed the disk and placed in the dock again
- with Disk Management I mounted the VHDX backup file of the second partition
- with EaseUs I cloned the mounted drive to unallocated space
- I reinstalled the hard disk in the laptop
- after booting I used EasyBCD by NeoSmart to edit the boot menu for the second OS
- in the second partition I mounted the system hive and edited MountedDevices, leaving the header but removing all drive letters
 
- I booted to each OS and updated windows
- on the other machine I mounted the VHDX file made of the corrupt drive and copied out everything new since the previous backup

The entire process went very fast due to the clone feature of EaseUS.

Comment: If downvoting a reason should be given.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erick Anderson's response above for pointing me in the right direction. In my case I could not use PowerShell since I was booted into a Windows Recovery Environment trying to follow these steps.

I was, however, able to fully use `DISM` to finally get the same tasks accomplished (without PowerShell). Here are the full step-by-step details on how to restore a Windows installation from a system image backup created with the "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" feature, especially when the official steps fail:

https://gist.github.com/ritchiecarroll/6def10ed017d8cd4b7b00daffeccfa13

This also includes steps on how to manually recreate the disk partitions required by Windows, should you lose all that as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you need to do a block copy from PhysicalDriveX to PhysicalDriveY .

x is the disk number which you get after mounting your VHDx and Y is the disk number of your SSD

mount the VHDx in read-only mode and open a handle to PhysicalDriveX -- H1

open a handle to PhysicalDriveY, lock the target SSD's PhysicalDriveY file -- H2

Read from H1

write to H2

Unlock H2 and you are done !

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I "block copy"? Thanks.

Comment: "I then installed a fresh OS using my original DVD (of Windows 8) on the SSD"

"so that I can get back my old and working OS."

Mount the VHDx and do granular file recovery on your personal files... Why do you want to screw up the new OS install ?

Comment: Because, as in my case, the OP had a working OS before and didn't want to spend the time to bring the new one up to usefulness (software installs, option settings, etc.).