# Is it necessary to do a block copy when replacing Windows OS?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, windows-backup, microsoft-surface-pro

So, here is what I did:

1. I made an image of my 400GB OS partition with the following command:

`wbAdmin start backup -backupTarget:F: -include:C:`

2. I tried to split the partition into C: (100GB)and D: (300GB) but Disk Manager would not let me.
3. I reset the OS to factory and tried again to resize C: to 100GB but Disk Manager would not let me.
4. I used a 3rd party utility to resize C: and then created a D: partition on the empty space.

Now, what I need is to restore my OS and programs from the VHD produced by `wbAdmin` to my new **smaller** partition.

5. I booted from a Acronis True Image 2014 boot disk and tried to restore the VHD, but the software will not let me select just the partition I want to restore to.

The internet people say you have to do a [block-by-block](https://superuser.com/a/793845/11933) copy and the target partition has to be equal or bigger than the source partition.

Is this true, and if so, why is that?

I ask because I was thinking of booting from a Acronis True Image boot disk and doing a **File Restore** where it replaces all the files from the VHD onto the partition.