# Can I copy my Windows partition to USB and boot from that?

Tags: windows

I have two partitions (Linux and Windows) on my laptop, and I'd like to free up some space on the hard drive.

Can I dd The Windows partition to another storage device (USB stick, SD card, etc.) and then successfully boot Windows from that device later? Or is there some security mechanism that will prevent this working?

My Windows 7 installation is the one that came with my Lenovo laptop. I have no CD nor 'Recovery CD'.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/213145/how-to%C2%A0convert-a-physical-windows-or-linux-pc-to-a-virtual-machine/ http://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk this should help

Answer (score 0):

No you just can't copy and boot from a partition that easy. Because there are system files, master boot record, log files, etc, you need to have in certain places. Therefor you can't. But you can backup the whole windows and use it when you need it

Comment: How does `dd` not preserve the places of system files, master boot record, etc.? Can you provide some explanation of these elements in such a way that it becomes clear how `dd` is insufficient?