# How can I transfer data from a virtualbox .vhd to a physical harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, multi-boot, virtualization, arch-linux

I have a virtual machine (Arch Linux) on a Windows 10 Host. The virtual hard drive is stored in a .vhd file.

I have a desktop that is currently Windows but I'm going to dual boot with the main partition being Arch Linux.

I want to transfer all the files and programs that I've downloaded on my Arch VM to the hard drive on the new desktop.

What tools can do this?

On a side note, how can I make the partition with Arch the one that boots by default?

Comment: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/mount-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-file-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying a VHD to a physical disk](https://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk)

Comment: And also https://serverfault.com/questions/296697/how-can-i-copy-a-vhd-image-back-to-a-physical-disc