# recover lost partitions in dual boot system

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, grub

I had a dual boot system with Linux and Windows 11 on it. The system booted into grub.

I made a mistake and used the tool documented here: [Copying a VHD to a physical disk](https://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk)
and it wrote the VHD on my boot system and now the system does not boot.

It boots into grub prompt and stops there.

Is there any way that I can recover windows or Linux partitions?

## Edit 1

I am able to boot into Windows by changing the boot sequence in the BIOS setting. But it seems that I lost the Linux partition.

Or maybe I lost the grub setting to boot into Linux. How can I update the grub configuration file?

Can GParted look for lost portions and activate them?

Is there any utility to looking for lost portions and trying to recover them?

Comment: If your goal is to get the system bootable without reinstalling, then you are probably out of luck. If you just want to recover your user data, have a look at [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

Comment: You have overwritten some or all of your Linux partitions and most of the the bytes are lost forever. Fair bet is something like `photorec` as @mashuptwice recommended. Best bet is to re-install and restore your files data files from backup.